# How to use the "imread" in skimage to read as well as write?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

how to use the read function in skimage to read as well as write an image?

"Code written in python opencv"

```
     cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
     imagenew = cv2.imread(filename)
```

"Code written in python skimage"

```
     filename=imread(image,as_gray=True) 
     imagenew=imread(filename,as_gray=True)
```

Comment: `imsave` maybe?

Comment: Given the name "imread" and documented functionality being "Load an image from file.", it's rather unlikely you can use such function to **write** an image. What you should do is read the documentation and find a function that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using skimage it should be following, I am assuming you are using skimage

```
filename= skimage.io.imread(fname, as_gray=True) # Load image
imagenew = skimage.io.imsave(fname, image) # save image
```

You can read more details [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread)

Comment: skimage.io.imsave(filename,im_gray) for saving. 
              im_gray=skimage.io.imread(filename,as_gray=True) for reading.